# PHP COM read MS word..works perfect...BUT

Tags: php, com+

I'm trying to read word files using the code given below (I got it from somewhere).

But, even though it works perfect on my system (windows 7 home, 64 bit), it doesn't work on the system of the person who actually needs it (windows 7 ultimate, 32 bit).

I've tried it on another laptop (windows 7 ultimate, 32 bit) and it doesn't work on it either. Unfortunately, we don't have a greater variety of OS here, so I'm stuck with these two types of windows 7. And yeh....we're trying to develop an application for .doc files so we absolutely need COM. We're using libraries for reading/writing .docx but our client needs .doc....

Check out my code...

```
class wordconvert
{
    /* variables */
    var $filename;  # Original File name with optional path.
                    # If no path provided, will be looked for in 
                    # My Documents.
    var $convert_to=0;
                   # Extension (as a string) or number (See Doc on 
                   # SaveAs method below),doc extension is the default.
    var $visible=0;# 0=Hidden, 1= Visible, hidden is the default.

    /* Constructor */

    function wordconvert($filename,$convert_to=0,$visible=0) 
    {
        if (!file_exists($filename))
        {
            echo "File $filename doesn't exist";
            exit();
        }

        $filename_path=  substr($filename,0,-4);

        if (is_string ($convert_to))
        {
            $convert_to= strtolower($convert_to);

            switch ($convert_to) 
            {
                case "doc":
                    $convert_to=0;
                    Break;
                case "dot":
                    $convert_to=1;
                    Break;
                case "txt":
                    $convert_to=2;
                    Break;
                case "rtf":
                    $convert_to=6;
                    Break;
                case "htm":
                    $convert_to=8;
                    Break;
                case "html":
                    $convert_to=8;
                    Break;
                case "asc":
                    $convert_to=9;
                    Break;
                case "wri":
                    $convert_to=13;
                    Break;
                case "wps":
                    $convert_to=28;
                    Break;
                default:
                    $convert_to=0;
            }
        }
        # Instantiate MSWord
        $word=new COM("Word.Application") or die("Cannot start MS Word");

        $word->visible = $visible ;

        #Open the original file in word.
        echo $filename;
        $word->Documents->Open($filename)or die("Cannot find file to convert");

        #Save the new file
        $word->ActiveDocument->SaveAs($filename_path,$convert_to); 

        /*
        Doc on quit method:
        expression.Quit(SaveChanges, Format, RouteDocument)
        */

        $word->quit(0); #0: Quit without saving
        # print "done!";

    }#End of func

}#End of class
```

So we basically need to use the `wordconvert()` function given above and although it works like magic in windows 7 home, 64 bit, it merely dies out saying

> "Cannot find file to convert"

in windows 7 ultimate, 32 bit!!

I tried out the following solution as well...
http://figured-it-out.com/figured-out.php?sid=24

but nothing happened! Any ideas....
And yeh...the php configuration is almost the same on both the computers...

thanks guys...if it were not for you guys, people like me would've been jobless!! :)

Comment: this is my last resort...before i give up....

Comment: It's not a very *nice* solution, but if the use case is quite specific (as it sounds like it is) maybe you could have the client install the [Office compatibility pack](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3) and convert all .doc to .docx before reading them? Just install the above and `exec('C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\wordconv.exe -oice -nme input.doc output.docx');` - and use your `libraries for reading/writing .docx` on everything?